# emerge install package with flag which not in ruby_targets

Tags: python, gentoo, ruby, emerge, portage

```
$ emerge --info | grep ruby 
..... RUBY_TARGETS="ruby23" ......
```

And I run emerge with `--newuse` and `--deep`, it will ask me to add use flag with `ruby22`.  These packages are not in `@system`.

These packages are:

```
>=virtual/rubygems-14 ruby_targets_ruby22
>=dev-ruby/rdoc-6.0.1 ruby_targets_ruby22
>=dev-ruby/rubygems-2.7.4 ruby_targets_ruby22
```

These packages have use flag `ruby_targets_ruby23`, and must I install them with ruby22?

If I remove these use flag with ruby22, it will notify a conflict.

If I run emerge with `--depclean`, there is nothing to remove.

And the same with python, I have no flag with python3_6 and python3_4, but it always installs them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of ruby is that `minitest` & `rdoc` package are use stable version.

The reason of python is that a flag use `pdf` which depends package only can use python3_4 in stable version.

There are too many dependancies, I decide to use the stable version and also install test version.